# mod_rewrite won't rewrite directory rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^alice.html$ bob.html
```

This works fine. However, changing the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^get/?$ get.php
```

and I get a 404.

Funnily enough it works on my local (XAMPP) machine, but not on my host (GoDaddy). Any thoughts?

Edit: It seems that rewrite rules only work when they're not in a directory format (i.e. have a file extension).

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled? Because the latter can also be caused by MultiViews.

Comment: Yep, definitely enabled, the alice rule definitely worked. I tried putting Options -Multiviews at the top of .htaccess but got 500 Internal server errors

Comment: Ah, I got it, it's Options -MultiViews with a capital V. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to add "Options -MultiViews" to the top of .htaccess